# How to prevent Py_Finalize closing stderr?

Tags: python, c++, cython, pythoninterpreter

I have a c++ code that loads a python interepter which uses stderr:

```
intereptor.pyx
stderr_dup = os.fdopen(sys.stderr.fileno(), 'wb', 0)
```

The problem is that after Py_Finalize is called, stderr is closed and I can't use it in c++.
should I just reopen it in c++ by

```
open(stderr)
```

Or I can prevent this behaviour from the python side (os.dup/dup2)?
I tired replacing the above fdopen with:

```
stderr_dup = os.dup(sys.stderr.fileno())
```

But Py_Finalize still closes stderr.

Comment: so its expected from it to close stderr?
how should I open it back in c++? I need to save it before calling Py_Initilize?

Comment: Can you dup stderr into an additional fd, and then set that fd as stderr once the Python stuff is finished? For example: `int stderr_copy = dup(stderr); ... Python ...; dup2(stderr_copy, stderr)`.

Comment: @JackHumphries that seems to work!, thanks! you can add it as an answoer if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dup `stderr` into an additional file descriptor, and then set that file descriptor as `stderr` once the Python stuff is finished.

```
int stderr_copy = dup(stderr);
// ... Python ...
dup2(stderr_copy, stderr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this from the Python side far more easily:

```
stderr_dup = os.fdopen(sys.stderr.fileno(), 'wb', 0, closefd=False)
```

From the documentation:

> If closefd is False and a file descriptor rather than a filename was given, the underlying file descriptor will be kept open when the file is closed.

Comment: looks promising, but Im surprized it didn't work.
After Py_Finilize I have stderr="Bad file descriptor"

Comment: Cannot reproduce that here. `fprintf(stderr, ...)` works just fine after calling `Py_Finalize`. Are you sure there's not something else closing stderr?

Comment: Im doing a dlclose on the python_lib, not sure if related.

Comment: I suggest you whittle your program down to a [mre] that others can use to verify their suggestions. Very often the real problem is found during this process

Comment: I guess the python unload.

Comment: If only there was a tool you could ask to stop the program when a certain function was called... Sounds like a better idea than guessing.

Comment: what function is called when python is unloaded? (not exit_handler, I mean real unload)

Comment: Your statement is that python closes stderr "on unload", so I suggest you put a breakpoint on the close system call and see what actually closes stderr.